# Django get records using OuteRef filtering by max value

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model called `CGDSStudy` with fields `name`, `url`, and `version`:

```py
class CGDSStudy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    version = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

Multiple versions of the same study can exist with the same URL, but I only want to retrieve studies of **the last version**. Here are three failed attempts:

**Attempt 1:**

```py
from django.db.models import Max, OuterRef, Exists

cgds_studies = CGDSStudy.objects.all()
cgds_studies = cgds_studies.filter(
    Exists(CGDSStudy.objects.annotate(max_version=Max('version')).filter(url=OuterRef('url'), max_version=OuterRef('version')))
)
```

This attempt retrieves all studies instead of the studies from the last version.

**Attempt 2:**

```py
cgds_studies = cgds_studies.filter(
    version=Max(CGDSStudy.objects.filter(url=OuterRef('url')).values('version'))
)
```

This attempt raises the error `"cgdsstudy.version" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

**Attempt 3:**

```py
cgds_studies = cgds_studies.filter(
    version=CGDSStudy.objects.filter(url=OuterRef('url')).annotate(max_version=Max('version')).values('max_version')[0]
)
```

This attempt raises the error `This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F, OuterRef, Subquery

CGDSStudy.objects.alias(
    max_version=Subquery(
        CGDSStudy.objects.filter(url=OuterRef('url'))
        .order_by('-version')
        .values('version')[:1]
    )
).filter(version=F('max_version'))
```